# Digitar link na URL não carrega a página

Tags: react

estou com um problema estranho. Estou fazendo a navegação de uma SPA usando react router v4, está funcionando se vc inicia a navegação do root, porém se vc digitar o endereço direto na URL ele da um erro.

Segue abaixo o código das partes relevantes e a imagem com o erro.

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import App from './main/app'

ReactDom.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

import Header from '../layout/header'
import SidebarLeft from '../layout/sidebarLeft'
import Center from '../layout/center'
import SidebarRight from '../layout/sidebarRight'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <main>
                    <SidebarLeft />
                    <Center />
                    <SidebarRight />
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

center.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Dashboard from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard'
import Gates from '../pages/gates/gates'
import Doors from '../pages/doors/doors'
import Lights from '../pages/lights/lights'
import Garden from '../pages/garden/garden'
import Agenda from '../pages/agenda/agenda'
import Activities from '../pages/activities/activities'


const page404 = ({ location }) => (
    <div>
        <h1>404 Error</h1>
        <h2>Page not found!</h2>
        <code>{location.pathname}</code>
    </div>
)


class Center extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="center">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/admin/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path='/admin/gates' component={Gates} />
                    <Route path='/admin/doors' component={Doors} />
                    <Route path='/admin/lights' component={Lights} />
                    <Route path='/admin/garden' component={Garden} />
                    <Route path='/admin/agenda' component={Agenda} />
                    <Route path='/admin/activities' component={Activities} />
                    <Route render={page404} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Center
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <base href="/">

    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app.css">

    <!-- Temporario -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>NK</title>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        Você precisa do Javascript habilitado para funcionar
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Talvez seja a falta de definir a tag `<base href="/">` no arquivo **index.html**

Comment: Você está no browser e não no servidor (server-render) então precisa usar HashRouter ao invés de BrowserRouter